# How to move the correct slider if they have the same name class using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I just have a problem in my code. I have two classes with the same name and like i'm using imacros in firefox 38 i can not select my class using $ symbole. So i just use the following command!

```
window.content.document.getElementsByClassName("slider-handle")[0].setAttribute('style', "left: 49.4845%;");
```

The problem that happen to me now! There's two classes with the same name slider-handle so are two divs with the same name and only select me the first, the incorrect slider.
the code of the slider is the same for both.

```
<div class="slider-handle min-slider-handle round" style="left: 0%;" tabindex="0"></div>
```

I just tried to change the value of the second slider , which is in the right hand but only move me which is in the left hand. page of sliders

Comment: So you want to select the second one instead of the first one? Then change `[0]` (0 selects the first) to `[1]` (1 selects the second).

Comment: I tried that i put reference page the first change second not

Comment: So you want to change both? 1st and 2nd?

Comment: @CodeF0x  the problem is with the hide class he is using in the second slider.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.content.document.getElementsByClassName("slider-handle")[0].setAttribute('style', "left: 49.4845%;");
```

Just replace **[0]** with the **[1]**

```
window.content.document.getElementsByClassName("slider-handle")[1].setAttribute('style', "left: 49.4845%;");
```

Or Just try using IDs(ofcourse! different) for removing any confusion.

Comment: Can you check the page put console run the command and works for the first but for the second not

Comment: @omaromar Yes I indeed checked and  its working.  You Just need to remove the hide class from the second slider... as it hide that one

Comment: Yes now is working fine ! Sir can you say me too how to delete the class using javascript to avoid doing manually?

Comment: Yes , Just use document.getElementsByClassName("slider-handle")[1].classList.remove("hide")  And please do consider upvoting the answer and accepting it .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about this answer but;

If you have two classes and Div's with the same name then as far as I'm aware you will target the one that comes first. Try changing the name of the class's or the Div's to be more unique to what you are doing e.g

```
<div class = "firstSlider-Handle" ... </div>
```

Use the above for one of the classes and for the second one use

```
<div class = "secondSlider-Handle ... </div>"
```

These are only suggestion ideas but having two classes and div's withe the same name will create issues